# Problema al mostrar elemento Html desde Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

tengo una tabla en HTML y quiero mostrar y ocultar una etiqueta label que esta dentro de un  cuando se selecciona un check, por defecto la etiqueta se muestra oculta, el problema es que si pongo el codigo css en un fichero aparte JavaScript no me muestra la etiqueta label, pero si pongo el codigo CSS enbebido en el HTML si funciona. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

pongo el código para que quede claro.

código html del check que llama al Js y del label que quiero mostrar:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="idCheckApellidos" name="checkApellidos" value="apellidos" onclick="mostrarApellidos()" ></input>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label id="labelApe2">Apellido2:</label></td>
```

Código CSS mediante el cual oculto la etiqueta:

```
#labelApe2 {
display: none;
```

}

código Javascript para mostrar la etiqueta:

```
function mostrarApellidos() {

var checkeado = document.getElementById('idCheckApellidos').checked;

if (checkeado) {
    document.getElementById('labelApe2').style.display = '';
} 
else {
    document.getElementById('labelApe2').style.display = 'none';
}
```

}

Si en lugar de poner el CSS en un fichero externo lo coloco enbebido si que funciona, pero necesito que esté en un fichero esterno.

ejemplo del label con css enbebido que si que funciona, se muestra con el Javascript:

```
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label id="labelApe2" style="display: none">Apellido2:</label></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bienvenido a la familia de SOes, tu problema está en que al definir la regla del CSS en el elemento `labelApe2`. Si dicha regla deja de existir, funciona tranquilamente.

Al utilizar la siguiente línea:

```
document.getElementById('labelApe2').style.display = '';
```

Estás eliminando el estilo del objeto con ID labelApe2, sin embargo las reglas que has definido en la hoja de estilos se mantienen vigentes.

```js
 function mostrarApellidos() {

var checkeado = document.getElementById('idCheckApellidos').checked;
console.log(checkeado); // Aqui vemos que valor tiene la variable
if (checkeado) {
    document.getElementById('labelApe2').style.display = '';
} 
else {
    document.getElementById('labelApe2').style.display = 'none';
}

}
```

```css
 /*#labelApe2 {
display: none;
}*/
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox" id="idCheckApellidos" name="checkApellidos" value="apellidos" onclick="mostrarApellidos()" ></input>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label id="labelApe2" style="display:none;">Apellido2:</label></td>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, ahora lo entiendo. ¿Pues entonces no hay mas remedio que poner el estilo embebido? o ¿hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: muchas de nadas, sí hay una manera de hacerlo y tienes que hacerlo con una clase en lugar de un ID, dicha clase te definirá el display none, luego en JavaScript agregas y quitas la clase haciendo lo siguiente: document.getElementById("labelApe2").className = "";

Comment: Tomo nota, gracias de nuevo ;)

Comment: de nada, sigue así, con todo el power 2.0! :D